# What is a weight-shift-control category aircraft?

Tags: flight-controls

Aircraft categories include:

- Airplane
- Rotorcraft
- Glider
- Lighter than air
- Powered lift
- Powered parachute
- ***Weight-shift-control***

I'm familiar with all of these *except* for weight-shift-control.  What are they??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it's [a powered hang glider](http://goo.gl/Ux9ARd).

[image]

> Weight-shift control (WSC) aircraft means a powered aircraft with a framed pivoting wing and a fuselage controllable only in pitch and roll by the pilot’s ability to change the aircraft’s center of gravity (CG) with respect to the wing. Flight control of the aircraft depends on the wing’s ability to deform flexibly rather than on the use of control surfaces.

— [FAA H-8083-5 Weight Shift Control Aircraft Flying Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/)

They're commonly called "trikes" and are literally big delta-wing hang gliders with a lot more structure and an engine. [Check out a cockpit video of one in flight!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znP4T45iGqY)

Comment: And they are superb fun to fly.

Comment: But a non-powered hangglider still is cg-controlled, no?

Comment: How do they shift the cg? Are there flight controls?

Comment: @Lnafziger they shift the CG by moving the entire wing structure. That giant bar the front guy is holding on to moves the wing on a pivot. So you're moving the CG around the center of lift and changing the angle of attack all at the same time.

Comment: @StallSpin Cool!  It's really hard to tell that from the small picture.  It looks like part of the frame and he is just holding on!

Comment: @yankeekilo yes! ...but they fall outside the FAA's realm, from what I understand.

Comment: o.k. - I was thinking phenomenologically, not regulatory :D  The OP does not seem to specify FAA in particular. +1 in any case - do you have an AI prowling the FAA web site for you?

Comment: @yankeekilo hah, true. Lnafziger pasted right out of the FAA's list of categories so I didn't even skim for tags!

Comment: Well, when I asked "what is it" I didn't think that the regulatory authority mattered (although you correctly determined that it was an FAA category that I was asking about).